Schluter kerdi curb less shower transition to floor
I am buliding my curbless shower. I have floor pan from kerdi and was planning to do cement board on the bathroom floor but I am worried if it will be water tight. Can I use cement board or shall I use ditra membrane? How do I transition from shower pan to cement board or to ditra membrane?

How are you planning to get level with the shower pan? Ramp up to it? Set the pan down into lowered floor sections?

basically for kerbless you need to make the whole floor be the shower pan.

I should have it all leveled with cement board. Based on my calculations levels are going to match

Any seam should be sealed with waterproof tape, such as Kerdi-Band or something similar.
Install it by the instructions from the manufacturer, which is usually imbedded in thinset, but could be different depending on the product.
This is true with cement board or any other wall and floor covering meant for a shower.
